# Validity of visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk

I have multi visitor visa for six month in UK and I have traveled two times with each trip for two weeks and I want to travel for third time to stay only for two weeks. Is it possible?

Comment: By multi I assume you mean multiple entry ? Is your visa still valid ?

Comment: why wouldn't it be possible?